# Error invalid token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

Hola amigos espero puedan ayudarme

Estoy generando mi propio metodo para crear usuarios mediante identity solo que al gnerar token cuando lo quiero validar me sale invalid token les muestro:

**Idenditity.cs**

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Código telefónico", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Su código de seguridad es {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Código de correo electrónico", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Código de seguridad",
                BodyFormat = "Su código de seguridad es {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
```

**Metodo para crear usuario**

```
public static ApplicationUser CreateUserASP(string email, string roleName, string password)
    {
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext));

        var userASP = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Email = email,
            UserName = email,
        };

        var result = userManager.Create(userASP, password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            userManager.AddToRole(userASP.Id, roleName);
        }
        var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("ApplicationName");
        userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));

        string code = userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(userASP.Id);
        var callbackUrl = "https://localhost:44390/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=" + userASP.Id + " &code=" + code;
        userManager.SendEmail(userASP.Id, "Confirmar cuenta", "Para confirmar la cuenta, haga clic <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">aquí</a>");
        return userASP;
    }
```

**Metodo para confirmar email**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
    }
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hay que pasar `RequestVerificationToken` en la petición de Ajax:

***JavaScript:***

```
var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
$.post(url, { comment: postComment, id: postId, __RequestVerificationToken: token }, 
function (data) { … })
```

***Controller:***

```
[HttpPost] 
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult AddComment(string comment, int IssueID){
    ...
}
```

Por otra parte, no hay necesario usarlo cuando usar los métodos de `Formdata` o `Serialize`:

```
var formdata = $('#frmCreate').serialize();
//o
var formdata = new FormData($('#frmCreate').get(0));
```

Espero que esto ayude...